# Naming Dask Worker with Docker Swarm Templating

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dask, docker-swarm, dask-distributed

I'm currently using Docker Swarm to deploy/manage multiple Dask Workers across a cluster. For easier debugging I'd like to be able to name the workers based on what node in the Swarm it is running on.

The `dask-worker` command has a `--name` parameter, however, Docker's templating doesn't seem to work in the `entrypoint` or `cmd` options. e.g.

```yaml
...
  worker:
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["dask-worker", "tcp://scheduler:8786", "--name", "{{.Node.Hostname}}"]
    deploy:
      mode: global
...
```

Unfortunately, the `{{.Node.Hostname}}` templating only appears to work in the environment section of a `docker-compose.yml` file. So my next option was to try and set it via an environment variable like this:

```yaml
...
  worker:
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["dask-worker", "tcp://scheduler:8786"]
    environment:
      DASK_DISTRIBUTED__WORKER__NAME: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      mode: global
...
```

I've also been unsuccessful with this, as I assume the workers name cannot be set via an environment variable - though I've not been able to find exhaustive documentation of all the supported environment variable config names for dask, so could be a typo or incorrect guess.

Finally, I tried to take the environment variable and bring it back into the `entrypoint` command via bash templating. This also did not work as it appeared that the environment variable was not set at the time this command was evaluated:

```yaml
...
  worker:
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "dask-worker tcp://scheduler:8786 --name $FOO"]
    environment:
      FOO: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      mode: global
...
```

I'm out of ideas at this point, and wondering if anyone could figure out a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use service template variables on service environments and hostname, and if my memory server right, inside volume declarations.

Thus said, wouldn't `service.worker.hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"` do the trick? Also, your last attempt might work, if you espace $FOO in your command. If my memory serves right, you need to escape the $ sign with another $ sign in front. So instead of $FOO, try $$FOO - otherwise it will applay variable substitution on the host during container start and NOT when executing the command in the container.

If it does not, you can still write a small entrypoint script that wrapps your command and uses the environment variable you declared.

Comment: I used the $$ escape option. I was unaware of this, but it seems to have worked. Thanks. My entry point ended up looking like `entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "echo $$FOO"]`.